# replace multi regex or words by sed one liner

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, cpu-word

Linux RH 5.11

GNU `sed` version 4.1.5

I have the following file where I want to replace the value of `+` with another (version) value for all lines where the **KEY** value starts with either ***ABC***, ***DEF*** or ***XYZ*** by running one command (using `sed` group words capability while doing word wrap/regex based matches).

```
linux_user@linux_server123 [ ~ ] 18:37:18 :9152> cp ~/my-file.json ~/BKUP-my-file.json; cat ~/my-file.json 
{
  "versions": {
    "ABC_PROJECT_Product": "+",
    "IGNORE1_PROJECT_Product": "1.8.0.1371",
    "DEF_PROJECT_Product": "+",
    "XYZ_PROJECT_Product": "+",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECT_Product": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobal": "+",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobal": "+",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECTGlobal": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "+",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "+",
    "IGNORE3_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "1.0.0.4913",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECTLocalREBS": "+",
    "IGNORE4_PROJECTLocalREBS": "1.1.0.865",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "+",
    "IGNORE3_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "1.0.0.4913",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "+",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "+",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECT_ProductIDNSS": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "+",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "+",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECTLocalSpecial": "+",
    "IGNORE4_PROJECTLocalSpecial": "1.1.0.865",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "+",
    "IGNORE5_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "2.1.0.683",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "+",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSpecial": "+"
  }
}
```

.

```
cp ~/BKUP-my-file.json ~/my-file.json; 
sed_regex="\(ABC\|DEF\|XYZ\)"; 
sed -i "s/\(.*\"${sed_regex}_PROJECT.*\".*:.*\"\).*\(\".*\)/\11.22.333.4444\2/" ~/my-file.json; 
sed -n "/.*\(ABC\|DEF\|XYZ\)_PROJECT.*/p" ~/my-file.json 
    "ABC_PROJECT_Product": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECT_Product": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "XYZ_PROJECT_Product": "1.22.333.4444XYZ
    "ABC_PROJECTGlobal": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobal": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTLocalREBS": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTLocalSpecial": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "1.22.333.4444ABC
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "1.22.333.4444DEF
    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSpecial": "1.22.333.4444ABC
```

**Question 1:**

Why `sed` is putting `ABC` or `DEF` or `XYZ` in place of the actual `\2` value, which I understand should be either: `",` or just: `"` i.e. line entry in JSON object (with/without any space/tabs) in that line?

**Question 2:**
How can I get `"ABC_PROJECT_Product": "+",` value as:

`"ABC_PROJECT_Product": "1.22.333.4444",`

**Question 3:**
Any why the heck using this `sed` fixes question 1 & 2 both (apart from making it faster duh).

`sed -i "/.*\"${sed_regex}_PROJECT.*\"/ s/\(.*\".*\".*:.*\"\).*\(\".*\)/\11.22.333.4444\2/" ~/my-file.json;`

May be `awk` can do this easily?

Comment: where did `1.22.333.4444` come from?

Comment: See now.. typo forgot to include it.

Comment: Don't manipulate `json` with shell utilities. Use a tool with `json` validations such as `jq`.

Comment: are you allowed to install/use `jq` tool?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin totally agree `jq` (approval) got denied due to `security vulnurablilities` in it. Federal client here :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no sir! no `jq` or similar json parsing custom tools (written by someone like me at least) and Groovy takes more than 1 line to do anything.

Comment: What? Not approving `jq` then turning developers loose to attempt to hack `json` with shell tools (thereby creating an opportunity of inadvertently creating much more serious vulnerabilities), just sounds like backwards thinking `:)`

Comment: lol.. but why would `\2` is getting ABC/DEF/XYZ rather than getting `",` or `"`? and why when I first use the regex for searching `/.../` and just using plain `.*` (for capturing) with same word capture, it's not populating `\2` with those unwanted values (see Question 3), that's making me stay (late on Friday) at work so far.

Comment: @ArunSangal where do your managers think the GNU sed version you're using (I can tell by `-i`) came from if not written by someone like you? They should look at the known security vulnerabilities of using jq (https://www.cvedetails.com/product/33780/Jq-Project-JQ.html?vendor_id=15837) vs GNU tools (https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/72/GNU.html).

Comment: @EdMorton Sure, I'll look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1:

The sed string has a nested grouping, so `\2` refers to `\(ABC\|DEF\|XYZ\)`. That's why we see ABC, DEF, etc. at the end of each line. We can more clearly see the nesting by re-writing the sed string with the sed_regex variable substituted:

```
sed "s/\(.*\"\(ABC\|DEF\|XYZ\)_PROJECT.*\".*:.*\"\).*\(\".*\)/\11.22.333.4444\2/"
```

Question#2:

Something like this could work:

```
sed_regex="\(ABC\|DEF\|XYZ\)"; sed "s/$sed_regex\(_PROJECT.*\)\("+"\)/\1\211.22.333.4444/g"
```

Question #3:

The revised sed string in the OP doesn't use a nested grouping and the regex appears to properly match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

[@cdub answered your 3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908434/1745001) but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ sed -E '/"(ABC|DEF|GHI)_PROJECT/ s/[+]/11.22.333.4444/' file
{
  "versions": {
    "ABC_PROJECT_Product": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE1_PROJECT_Product": "1.8.0.1371",
    "DEF_PROJECT_Product": "11.22.333.4444",
    "XYZ_PROJECT_Product": "+",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECT_Product": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobal": "11.22.333.4444",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobal": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECTGlobal": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "11.22.333.4444",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalSSD": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE3_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "1.0.0.4913",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSSD": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECTLocalREBS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE4_PROJECTLocalREBS": "1.1.0.865",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE3_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "1.0.0.4913",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductODNS": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductIDNS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE2_PROJECT_ProductIDNSS": "1.1.0.830",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalIDNS": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "11.22.333.4444",
    "DEF_PROJECTGlobalODNS": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECTLocalSpecial": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE4_PROJECTLocalSpecial": "1.1.0.865",

    "ABC_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "11.22.333.4444",
    "IGNORE5_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "2.1.0.683",
    "DEF_PROJECT_ProductSpecial": "11.22.333.4444",

    "ABC_PROJECTGlobalSpecial": "11.22.333.4444"
  }
}
```

The above requires GNU (or OSX/BSD) sed as you're already using for `-E`. Alternatively this will work with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
awk '/"(ABC|DEF|XYZ)_PROJECT/{sub(/[+]/,"11.22.333.4444")} 1' file
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, I basically used an example and was using a variable sed_regex="somevalue" to replace where it was set in a loop to either IJK, LMN, or ABC, DEF, ... so couldn't use single quote, otherwise, your answer is perfect.

Comment: No, you can and should be using single quotes around the script since doing anything else unnecessarily exposes your whole script to the shell for interpretation before sed even sees it. To use the contents of a shell variable in a script is just `cmd 'foo'"$shellvar"'bar'`, for example `sed_regex='ABC|DEF|GHI'; sed -E '/"('"$sed_regex"')_PROJECT/ s/[+]/11.22.333.4444/' file`